# PHP move_uploaded_file over specific ports

Tags: php, port, file-transfer

Ok, so I've created a project where a client can drag and drop files onto our server and all works great! Now I've been asked to have the files that are being uploaded/transferred by our clients over a specific port range (let's say between 10000 and 11000 for argument sake). I do not know how to accomplish this. My current uploading function looks something like this:

File's name: *test/upload.php*

```
$dir = "path/to/directory/";
$tempFile = $_FILE['file']['tmp_name'];
$tagetFile = $dir.$_FILE['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
```

Where `$_FILE` is a file being uploaded.

Please disregard any syntax or spelling error in the code above, it works perfect at the moment. I have removed a lot of code to give a simplistic idea of what my code is currently doing.

If any configuration changes to PHP are to be made, they need to target this directory specifically as the rest of our website needs to stay on the current port. I am not exactly sure where to begin with specifying the ports to be used for file transfers. The file transfers are purely client to server and will never be vice-versa. We do have an FTP server setup however if possible, we'd like to remain off of it. I am not sure if what I am asking is possible otherwise.

I am using the Dropzone.js plugin (from here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/), however all the PHP code is mine.

I am not sure if something like the code below (from [here](http://www.ewhathow.com/2013/09/check-if-a-tcp-port-like-http-port-80-is-open-using-php/)) is the way to go, I've never used the fsockopen function before.

```
$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout); 

$responding = 1;
if (!$fp) { $responding = 0; } 

$tend = microtime(true);

fclose($fp);
```

All answers are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to save the file server side by sending it to a different service on a separate port, or do you want the client uploading it to a different port?

Comment: We want the file upload to occur on another port. Some of these files could take several minutes to transfer and we could have 100 of these large files being transferred simultaneously. We are looking to reduce load and have file transfers occur on a specific port range away from our public website

Comment: Changing ports does not really reduce load.

Comment: @Evert It does if it's a different server.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the client to upload the file on a different port, you will need to stand up a web server on that port. You could tell your current server to listen on that port, but that would do nothing to reduce load on your main website, so a separate machine is necessary. The new machine will have to be set up to listen to only the file upload port, but will need to contain your server (Apache, etc), PHP, and have access to the network storage location for your files.

If you have one, you may need to configure your firewall so traffic comes in to the correct machine depending on which port it is sent to.

The actual PHP code you use will not really be any different from what you have working now. Your JS code will need to be updated to it posts to the server using port 10000 or whatever you choose.

Here's a simple diagram that may help.
[image: Simple diagram]